# Отключение стилей bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, css

Доброго утра!
Возможно ли отключать стили Twitter Bootstrap через, например, какой-либо класс?
Например, даем объекту <form> класс 'no-bootstrap' и все стили из фреймворка отключаются. Мне кажется не рациональным переписывать кучу свойств в стилях, чтобы придать стандартный вид одному объекту.

Заранее всем спасибо.

Comment: Зачем сначала добавлять стили bootstarp, а потом убирать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, класса для reset(сброса), к сожалению не существует, так как это просто противоречит концепции CSS (о том что все свойства прописанные к объекту складываются и перекрываются при совпадении в зависимости от приоритета). Поэтому для решения вашей задачи нужно будет описывать стили тэга form в ручную, но обязательно либо в конце css файла bootstrp, либо в файле который подключается после него.

Comment: Спасибо, как сбрасывать я знаю, думал может это можно упростить.